# How to optimize the running time of this code?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, optimization

This intersection two-dimensional array represents the number of times that scenic spot B also appeared when scenic spot A appeared. Now this code takes about 1 minute and 30 seconds to get the result. Is it possible to get the result of this code in 10 seconds?

```
for a in range ((len(user_record[0]))):#len(user_record[0]) is 1136
    b = 0
    for b in range ((len(user_record[0]))): #len(user_record[0]) is 1136
        c = 0
        Intersection[a][b] = 0
        for c in range (len(user_record)): #len(user_record) is 31
            Intersection[a][b] = Intersection[a][b] + user_record[c-1][a] * user_record[c-1][b]
```

Comment: What is it doing?

Comment: @Sayse
It is a two dimensional array to calculate how many times that every two tourist spots (two as a pair) is being visited by all the visitor.

Comment: Move more code out of the inner loop body. E.g. the list `Intersection[a]` is constant within the inner `b` loop. `Intersection[a][b]` is constant within the inner `c` loop. The `b = 0` is superfluous. Don't reevaluate `len(user_record)` in the loops.

Comment: Which is true: Your comment `#0~108` or `len(user_record[0]) = 1136` ? Can you update your code to reflect the exact limits? Please remove misleading comments.

Comment: @pqans          
I have changed the wrong comments. This is true: len(user_record[0]) is 1136, len(user_record) is 31.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest moving your data to numpy structures. After that, there are many functions like [intersect1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) that resolve this kind of problems in the right manner.